# How to clean inactive Eglot events buffers up simultaneously?

Tags: eglot

Editing multiple Eglot-enabled buffers generates several `*EGLOT ... events* (Fundamental)` buffers.
Even though `M-x eglot-shutdown(-all)` kills *active* events buffers being used for communications with language servers, but it doesn't kill *inactive* buffers which have already lost connections with language servers.